# Update TimeZone when changed in iOS app

Tags: ios, nstimezone

In my application, the user can set the TimeZone at the time of sign up. If the user moves to some other TimeZone, then the TimeZone of the device is different from the TimeZone of the user profile.

How can I update TimeZone in the user profile?

Comment: "imitate" and why would you want to manually set the time zone? Even if the user doesn't move the time zone will change twice every year with daylight savings. It's already a massive pain working with time zones. Save yourself the hassle and just use the device time zone.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to make changes in the app when timezone changes.

you can use the following code in the app

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector: @selector(your_method_that_fires_when_timezone_changes)
                                             name:NSSystemTimeZoneDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

and you can even use UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification.